# AngularJS - Not able to update model programatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model

When I update my model through method, model does not update. Below is my AngularJS code:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

app.controller('businessCtrl', function($scope, Business) {
  $scope.businesses = Business.query();  // getting data using REST
  $scope.currentBusinessIndex = 0;
  $scope.changeBusinessIndex = function (indx) {
      if (indx) {
          $scope.currentBusinessIndex = indx;
      } else {
          $scope.currentBusinessIndex = 0;
      }
  };
});
```

Below is the HTML:

```
<ul class="signups">
    <li ng-controller="businessCtrl" ng-repeat="business in businesses">
        <div class="user pull-left"  ng-click="changeBusinessIndex($index)">
            <img ng-src="http://localhost:8081{{business.logo.uri}}" alt="business logo" >
        </div>
        <div class="info" ng-click="changeBusinessIndex($index)">
            <h6 ng-cloak>{{business.name}}</h6>
            <small ng-cloak>{{business.streetAddress + ',' + business.city + ',' + business.country}}</small>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="business-image" class="main-container" ng-controller="businessCtrl">
    <img ng-src="http://localhost:8081{{businesses[currentBusinessIndex].logo.uri}}" alt="Business Logo">
</div>
```

**Problem:**

In changeBusinessIndex() method, when I modify currentBusinessIndex, it does not modify and as a result image in "business-image" div is not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating two different instances of businessCtrl, one for the li (let's call it businessCtrl1) and one for the business-image div (let's call that businessCtrl2). When you are calling changeBusinessIndex() in the li-instance it will update currentBusinessIndex for businessCtrl1, but not for the other instance.

Set ng-controller="businessCtrl" on an element that wraps both the li and the business-image divs to get a single instance of the controller, something like:

```
<div ng-controller="businessCtrl>
    <li ng-repeat ... etc ></li>
    <div id="business-image" ... ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it seems strange that you call twice `ng-controller="businessCtrl"` (with the same name). But if you interesting to use two different  controllers I would store `currentBusinessIndex` into the Service and use it as storage. Since service is singleton, you can register the service to both controllers and by this way your logic should work.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl_1">
    <button ng-click="showMe();">press  me</button>
    <pre>{{myStorage.getIndex()}}</pre>
</div>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl_2">
    <pre>{{myStorage.getIndex()}}</pre>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl_1($scope,  myStorage) {   
    $scope.myStorage = myStorage;

    $scope.showMe = function(){
      myStorage.setIndex(3);
    }
}

function MyCtrl_2($scope,  myStorage) {   
    $scope.myStorage = myStorage;    
}


myApp.factory('myStorage', function () {

       var currentBusinessIndex = 0;

       return {
            getIndex: function () {                
               return currentBusinessIndex;
            },
           setIndex: function (index) {
               currentBusinessIndex = index;               
            }
        }
  });
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PxdSP/1004/)**</kbd>